# AC 220v motor speed controller for raspberry

Tags: hardware

I would like to control an AC 220V Motor via raspberry. 
All I could find until now, is about stepper, and 12/24V Motor ...

Any Idea where I could find a simple Hardware to use in combination with raspberry ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as a minimum you'll need a relay switch and a transistor (because you cannot directly plug relay into the Pi). schematics might looks like this:

[image]

and there's more [detailed explanation](http://raspberrypihobbyist.blogspot.jp/2012/09/gpio-output-relay-interface.html) if you need it.

please, be very careful when working with 220v, it might easily kill you.

Comment: Thank you, That why I'm searching something out of the box... 
I was adviced on phidgets Solid State Relays, but I don't know if it is the right thing to control a motor ?
http://www.phidgets.com/products.php?product_id=3959

Comment: "Control Voltage Min - 4V" suggests it should work well enough with 5V.

Comment: To protect the relay contacts from the arcing which can be generated by switching off an inductive load (like an electric motor), an RC snubber can be used. [Designing RC Snubber Networks -PDF](http://www.cde.com/resources/catalogs/igbtAPPguide.pdf) has suggestions for the type and ratings of the resistor and capacitor, and [How to design an RC snubber for a solenoid relay driving an inductive load?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/42131/36731) has more information. Ready-made snubbers are available. For an AC motor, you *do not* want a simple diode snubber.